# Why doesn't after event of Flex slider fire if slides are moved rapidly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

Recenlty I have been implementing lazy loading in flex slider. I lazy load images using the `after` event of flex slider. I observed that if arrow icon is pressed rapidly and slides move fast then the `after` event is not fired. Here is a demo:

```js
$('#carousel').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  itemWidth: 210,
  itemMargin: 5,
  asNavFor: '#slider',
  after: function(slider) {
    console.log("after fired on " + slider.currentSlide);
    
    //$("#flex-carousel-H img").slice( ((slider.currentSlide + 1)*4), (((slider.currentSlide + 2)*4) + 1)).each(flexLazy);
  }
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  sync: "#carousel"
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>

<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please try clicking the right arrow icon in bottom thumbnail slider. You will observe that console doesn't log for every slide. But if we click slowly then console logs for every slide.

**Question:**
1. Why doesn't `after` event fire for every slide if slides are moved rapidly.
2. How to force `after` to fire even if slides are moved rapidly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found the answer to this already, but I had this same issue, instead of using the `after` callback which triggers when the animation finishes you should use the `before` callback. It triggers "before" the animation starts and it will always fire no matter how quickly you thumb through the slides.

Comment: That's what I ended up using.